# How to make this lightbox page effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, load, effect

How can I make this lightbox effect that they use on this website http://www.usatoday.com that when you click on a thumbnail the page loads in with that lightbox pop-over the content effect.

But the thing is **it's not just a simple lightbox** plugin because the link changes into the post link in the address bar.

I've looked around and all I could find are these: http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/ and http://fancybox.net/
but they are not really what I am looking for, since I really need the link to change in the address bar.

If anybody knows of a simple way to achieve this, please help me out :)

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This may be helpful for creating light box using jquery.
http://www.tonylea.com/2011/how-to-create-your-own-jquery-lightbox/

Comment: I don't need to know how to create my own lightbox effect, I already found plugins to do that, what I need is a way to add the link feature I was talking about. I need the link of the post thumbnail to appear in the address bar.